# How to have some form of concat/dynamic element in INDEX?

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation, search-indexing

In Sheet 1 I have 1, 2, 3, 4 in `A1:B2`

[image: Sheet1]

so that I can Sheet 2 can call cell `4:4` by `=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:B2;2;2)`,
[image: Sheet2]

Work's gerat! However, in Sheet 3 I have a table, identical to the one in sheet 1, that I would like to call in sheet 2. My real life issue in between Excel workbooks, hence why the [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) would not work. Thanks to [@gns100](https://superuser.com/users/726914/gns100) for pointing that out!

Hence my interest in doing something along the lines of `=INDEX(“Sheet”&A1&”!A1:B2”;2;2`) in row 2 in Sheet 2, where row 1 would be 1, 3, etc… like this (does not work), and [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) kinda does not work, as mentioned above.

[image: Sheet2 not wokring!]

In other words: How do use a dynamic element in inside INDEX?

Comment: you would use [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to convert the string to a valid range reference.

Comment: You should also be able to name that range.

Comment: @ScottCraner INDIRECT doesn’t work for me, as the references die if I close the sources workbook. They both need to be open to work with INDIRECT

Comment: @gns100 could you elaborate how naming any ranges would solve my issue? Thing is, that I need the part Sheet1!A1 to be dynamic, so that I can have the last one of two cell's change.

Comment: You can use CHOOSE: `CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"Sheet1","Sheet2"},0),Sheet1!A1:B2,Sheet2!A1:B2)`

Comment: @EricFail, in your comment you mention workbooks. That is a key piece of information you need to edit into your question. I think power query is needed to go across unopened workbooks or VBA to open/close unopened workbooks...

Comment: with the new info: `CHOOSE(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$2,Sheet3!$A$1:$B$2)` otherwise vba or power Query is the only other way.

Comment: @ScottCraner your model solved my issue! Thanks. It even works with my long string/path. An additional question if I may. Is there a way to patch together the string/file path and filename, soo I only have to write them once and then point to them in the function?

Comment: @ScottCraner posted a new question. https://superuser.com/questions/1772643/how-to-concat-or-something-like-it-sheet-file-path-reference-in-excel if you paste your answer here I coudl mark it as solved (the first part). Thanks again.