# How to CONCAT (or something like it) Sheet-file path reference in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation, simplification

I’m trying to simplify my Excel function my referencing a simple string I am using quite a few times.

In Sheet1 and Sheet2 and have a small matrix.

[image: Sheet1]
[image]

That I am calling from Sheet3 with the [INDEX functio](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)n. Like this `=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(B$4;{"Sheet1";"Sheet2"};0);Sheet1!A1:B2;Sheet2!A1:B2);D5;E5)` In my real life example, Sheet1 and Sheet2 in in another workbook, why the INDIRECT function would not work
I have a working function, like this.

[image: working]

But I would like to simplify it like this, `=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(B$4;{"Sheet1";"Sheet2"};0);B1;B2);D5;E5)` however this does not work?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot refer to a string that looks like a reference without INDIRECT.  CHOOSE only works in the first because the full reference is in the formula.  The minute you make the reference a string, it requires INDIRECT to convert to a real reference.  But as you stated in your [last question](https://superuser.com/questions/1772608/how-to-have-some-form-of-concat-dynamic-element-in-index) this will not work for you.  So you will need to use the full reference in the choose and not refer to a cell that has the text string.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for contributing here too. I’m truly surprised, that I can’t ‘build’ a reference! In my real-life issue, I have a full reference that is more +60 charters long, now I’m repeating that reference n number of times (across the sheet, and when I need to update my Sheet I have my make a (somewhat dicey) fined and replace across those n cells. I hope there’s some simple solution that we do not know about.

Comment: With formulas alone, there is not any other way.  You can write vba that creates the actual formula on the fly.  But that may still require the opening and closing the target sheet to ensure the links are made correctly.

Comment: use =A1&A2 is another option to concat()

Answer (score 0):

in  sheet3 cell B5 , put :

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(B$4&"!A1"),$D5-1,$E5-1)
```

copy, n paste to B6,C5,C6.

That should do.

Idea : use indirect() to 'resolve' the topleft 1st cell. Use offset() to choose which cell to choose.

Pls share if it works/not/understandable.